# How do I allow databases to run activex content when opened with VBA?

Tags: security, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, trust

In Access 2013 (64-bit) I'm opening another database (db2) when the user clicks a button on a form in db1. This is working. However, when it opens db2 I get the warning bar "Security warning: Some active content has been disabled. Click for more details" with a button to enable the content. This is annoying and when I open the database from db1 with forms also opened, when I click the button to enable the content all currently open forms are closed.

Both databases are in the same directory, and I have added this directory to the trusted locations. Is there something else I need to do to disable this warning bar without automatically trusting all databases (something I don't want to do)?

When I manually open each database, I don't see the warning bar appear, so I assume it's something to do with the VBA code I'm using:

```
Dim db2 As Variant
Set db2 = CreateObject("Access.Application")
db2.OpenCurrentDatabase "NewDb.accdb"    
db2.DoCmd.OpenForm "_View"
db2.DoCmd.OpenForm "_Home"
db2.UserControl = True
```

Comment: Do you see any difference with this change? `db2.OpenCurrentDatabase CurrentProject.Path & "\NewDb.accdb"`

Comment: Wow, yes I do! Write it as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the full path to `NewDb.accdb` when you call `OpenCurrentDatabase`.  I think you want the same folder as the first database (*db1*).  `CurrentProject.Path` will give you the full path of that folder ...

```vb
db2.OpenCurrentDatabase CurrentProject.Path & "\NewDb.accdb"
```

Comment: The important take-home part is that by specifying the full path it prevents the security warning that disables "Active" content (macros, vba code, etc) from showing.

Comment: Did I guess wrong?  I assumed without specifying the folder, you were opening a copy of `NewDb.accdb` from another folder ... one which was not set as a trusted folder.

Comment: It was opening the correct database (in the same directory as the current database) but for some reason, specifying the full path prevents the security warning. Right answer, wrong reason ;)

Comment: OK, I see now.  I never noticed that before.  I updated the answer to discard the explanation which was based on my wrong guess.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Access 2013 as I can't really see any reason for the differences.